# Don't go Vs. I'am not going

Tags: pronouns, present-tense, present-continuous

Please look at the statement which I know is ok.

> - I'm not going anywhere without you!

The second one I am not sure about is:

> - I don't go anywhere without you!

Are they both correct?

Comment: General (Present Simple) vs Right at the moment (Present Continuous)

Comment: Thanks. What about no and none?

Comment: Ask one question at a time. Please split your question into two separate ones but check for duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are both "correct", after a fashion, but "I don't go anywhere without you" is an unusual phrasing that would only be appropriate in a specific context:

> A:  Do you understand? Are my instructions clear?
>   B:  I understand -- **I don't go anywhere without you.**

We can assume that, previously, A told B, "Don't go anywhere without me", and so B is simply *repeating* A's instructions back to him.

Otherwise it would be more natural to say

> I **will not / won't** go anywhere without you.

or, more formally:

> I **shall not / shan't** go anywhere without you.